# How do I shift the line indent to a specific value?

Tags: indentation, normal-mode

Many times I run across a situation where a line is not indented properly. Ether through a paste, bad / not preferred indent plugin, or most often extra spaces offsetting the indent value. I usually fix this by `<<` or `>>` the line a few times to fix it up. In the case of extra spaces I'll do a `100<<` then a `>>` for each indent level I actually want.

The question is, like the <kbd>|</kbd> motion that lets you set the column by number `10|` sends the cursor to the 10th column. How can I specify the indent level?

An example (this does not work) with `shiftwidth=4 expandtab`:

```
The quick (indent level 0)
••••Brown Fox (indent level 1)
••••••••••Jumped over the lazy dog (indent level 2 with two extra spaces)
```

In this case I currently have to count the indent level of the last line (2) and add one for the extra spaces then type `3<<` then count the indent level of what I then `1>>` (or use `autoindent` and `==` command).

I'm asking for something like `1==` to force the indent to be indent level 1. Or in some cases `0==` for removing an indent all together.

I realize the above example does auto indenting on 1 or 0 lines (respectively) and so does not do what I'd like but hoped it would help illustrate the question better.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the [`:left`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Aleft) command:

> `:[range]le[ft] [indent]`
>   Left-align lines in `[range]`.  Sets the indent in the  lines to `[indent]` (default 0).  {not in Vi}

Note that `:left` sets the indent to *n* spaces, and is not aware of `shiftwidth` or `tabstop`, so using `:left 8` will use 8 spaces.

If you want to set the indentation level, you can easily define a command:

```
command! -nargs=1 Left execute 'left ' . &sw * <args>
```

Use `:Left 2` will set the indentation to 8 spaces.

To map this to <kbd><Leader>=</kbd>, you could use:

```
noremap <expr> <Leader>= ':left ' . str2nr(nr2char(getchar())) * &sw . '<CR>'
```

I'm not sure if this is the best way, but it's the only way I can manage... <kbd>\=2</kbd> will indent the current line to 8 spaces, and <kbd>5\=3</kbd> will indent the next 5 lines to 12 spaces.

---

A related hint that also solves your problem is setting the `shiftround` option.  From [`:help 'shiftround'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27nosr%27)

> Round indent to multiple of `'shiftwidth'`.  Applies to `>` and `<`
>   commands.  CTRL-T and CTRL-D in Insert mode always round the indent to
>   a multiple of `'shiftwidth'` (this is Vi compatible).

In your example, the first `<<` will "round" to 8 spaces. So your problem (using `3<<` and then `>>`) is solved. And as the help page says, you can also use `<C-d>` from insert mode.

Comment: Awesome! These solutions work perfect.